# Laravel 5.1 Register Package Middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am developing some middleware for my custom package. However, in order to use those package middleware, I have to manually add it in to `kernel.php` file into `$routeMiddleware`. So now, I have to manually add in these few extra line of code everytime when using my package.

```
'login.auth' => \Vendor\Package\http\middleware\loginAuth::class,
'login.guest' => \Vendor\Package\http\middleware\loginGuest::class,
'login.permission' => \Vendor\Package\http\middleware\loginPermission::class,
```

The list may get longer as the package grow. How can I have better way of registering package middleware without the need to manually register all of them to `$routeMiddleware`?

Comment: Currently there is no way of adding these lines automaticly. You have to put this in you documentation so every user knows these lines have to be added.

Comment: @Jerodev Thanks for your comment. I don't mean to automatically adding lines, but is there a way to do it on package service provider or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a route based middleware, do this in your  package service provider (boot method).

```
public function boot(\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router)
{
    $router->middleware('name', 'MiddlewareClass');
}
```

Also, for not route based middleware, class `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel` has these two public methods that you may call:

```
/**
* Add a new middleware to beginning of the stack if it does not already exist.
*
* @param  string  $middleware
* @return $this
*/
public function prependMiddleware($middleware)

/**
* Add a new middleware to end of the stack if it does not already exist.
*
* @param  string  $middleware
* @return $this
*/
public function pushMiddleware($middleware)
```

Answer (score 2):

For laravel 5.4 and above, use:

```
public function boot(\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router)
{
    $router->aliasMiddleware('name', 'MiddlewareClass');
}
```